# Express.JS Unable to resolve 307 error and CORS error

Tags: express, cors

A client-server api exchange run without issues. But when I use a VPN to load the client, the exchange fails with a 307 error and a CORS error.

With express.js on server side, the cors options are defined as follow :

```
const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://clientside.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  credentials: true
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

The configuration is ok and the reactjs client (situated at https://clientside.com) get the results from the server side (https://serverside.com) without any issues.

But when I use a VPN to load the reactjs client, the serverside doesn't give the results and I get a error code 307 and a CORS error « Access-Control-Allow-Origin » is missing.

How could I solve this issue. Why the origin corsOption is not sent to the client ?
Is there any option in express.js to solve this problem.

Thanks for your answers.